# Cholesky factorization with gonum

Tags: go, matrix-factorization, gonum

I am trying to use the Go [`gonum/mat` matrix library](https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat) to find the Cholesky factorization of a matrix.

The goal is to get similar results to Matlab `chol()`. In Matlab `chol(P_inno)` outputs:

```
P_inno = [0.10062    -0.042635    -0.072741    -0.1434;
-0.042635    0.21293    -0.02717    -0.052181;
-0.072741    -0.02717    0.26536    0.27184;
-0.1434    -0.052181    0.27184    0.86335] 

chol(P_inno) = 
0.31721    -0.13441    -0.22932    -0.45207
0    0.44143    -0.13137    -0.25585
0    0    0.44217    0.30432
0    0    0    0.70775
```

So far in Go I have matrix:

```
arr := []float64{0.067503,0,0,0,0,0.063724,0,0,0,0,0.11575,0,0,0,0,0.05}
P_inno := mat.NewSymDense(4, arr)

// attempt at Cholesky matrix
    var chol mat.Cholesky
    if ok := chol.Factorize(P_inno); !ok {
        fmt.Println("a matrix is not positive semi-definite.")
    }
    var t mat.TriDense
    fmt.Println(chol.UTo(&t))
```

The code doesn't work because `t TriDense` is empty. I'm not sure how to call `UTo()`.

The [library documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat) says

> The decomposition can be constructed using the Factorize method. The factorization itself can be extracted using the UTo or LTo methods, and the original symmetric matrix can be recovered with ToSym.

I could use help to understand how to do this step. I don't understand how to extract the actual factorization.

I have tried the fololwing:
`chol.UTo(&t)` and `chol.UTo(t)` (no value) used as value;
`chol.Factorize(P_inno)` returns boolean, not factorization.

Comment: `chol.UTo(&t)` doesn't return anything, as you can see from the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat#Cholesky.UTo). The method simply populates the `mat.TriDense` argument with the relevant L or U result of the factorization. Instead of passing `chol.UTo(&t)` to `fmt.Println`, simply print `t` afterwards https://go.dev/play/p/pjJwUiAKrVS

Comment: @blackgreen You were correct. I added your change ` chol.UTo(&t)`
 ` fmt.Println(t) ` and found the 4x4 matrix which matches the expected matlab output! Thanks a bunch!